# Absolute convergence condition for radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-t)^n$ be a power series. Let $X=\{|x-t|:\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n||x-t|^n$ converges$\}$. Let $R$ be the least upper bound of $X$ if $X$ is bounded and let $R=\infty$ if $X$ is unbounded. Prove that $R$ is the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-t)^n$.

If $b\in X$, then any $a\in[0,b]$ is also in $X$ because $a^n<b^n$ and we use the comparison test.

So suppose $|b|<R$. Then $|b|\in X$, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb^n$ converges absolutely.

Now suppose $|b|>R$. So $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n||b|^n$ diverges. We must prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb^n$ diverges. How can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Prove and use the following result:

> If a series $\sum a_n z^n$ converges then $\sum a_n (cz)^n$ converges absolutely for any $-1<c<1$.

---

**Further hint**: To show the above notice that we must have $a_nz^n$ bounded by some $K$. Now how can you rewrite the second sum with absolute value signs?

Comment: Tried to prove that but don't have an idea how to prove absolute convergence in this case. More hint?

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: So the terms in the second sum with absolute values are $\sum|a_nz^n|\cdot |c|^n$, which is bounded by $\sum |K|\cdot |c|^n$. So it converges by comparison test to the geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum a_n z^n$ converges, then certainly $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n z^n =0$. In fact, all you really need to know is that the numbers $|a_n z^n|$ are eventually smaller than some fixed positive number. For example, suppose that $|a_n z^n| < 12$ when $n \geq 100$. But then, if $|w| <|z|$ and $n \geq 100$, we get $|a_n w^n| = |a_n z^n| |\frac{w}{z}|^n \leq 12 |\frac{w}{z}|^n$ where $|\frac{w}{z}| < 1$. You should be able to deduce that $\sum a_n w^n$ converges absolutely from here by using what you know about geometric series.